# How do I get the parent tid of a taxonomy term in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal-8

I used the following to get the parent of a taxonomy term in drupal 8:

```
$parent = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->loadParents($termId);

$parent = reset($parent);
```

Now that I have the parent how do I get the parent tid from that?

Comment: Since $parent is an array of parent terms keyed by the term id I went with `reset(array_keys($parent))` if there's a better way please let me know.

Comment: For now `loadParents()` seems the only option, but `$term->parent->target_id` support can be added in https://www.drupal.org/node/2543726

Comment: Your `$parent` variable contains a `Term` object. You should use the `$parent->id()` method to get its tid.

Comment: array_key_first will get you the key which is the term id

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Now that you have the term parent with the code:

```
$parent = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->loadParents($termId);

$parent = reset($parent);
```

You can simply use the `$parent->id()` method to get your parent *tid*.

```
$parent_tid = $parent->id()
```

Comment: Was that always there? I don't know how I missed it. Thanks.

Comment: How can I implement this? Does this go in theme preprocess_node. Can I create a variable from this so that I can use the variable in a twig template?

Comment: yeah, you can use in most of the available preprocesses as `preprocess_node`, `preprocess_page`, `preprocess_theme`, `preprocess_route` and so on.

Answer (score 3):

```
$term = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->load($term_id);
$parent_term_id = $term->parent->target_id;
```

It will provide the parent id of the term if exist.

Answer (score 1):

You can pull the tree for the vocabulary and sift through that.

```
// assuming $termId is the child tid..
$tree = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->loadTree('VOCABULARY_NAME', 0);
for ($tree as $term) {
  if (in_array($termId, $term->parents)) {
    $parent_term = $term;
    break;
  }
}
```